# Programming in C - CS50 Mario pyramid blocks print - For loops difficulties

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

I am working on this problem from the CS50 class. I am still a beginner. What I need to program is this:

> Toward the end of World 1-1 in Nintendo’s Super Mario Brothers, Mario
> must ascend right-aligned pyramid of blocks, a la the below.
>
> screenshot of Mario jumping up a right-aligned pyramid
>
> Let’s recreate that pyramid in C, albeit in text, using hashes (#) for
> bricks, a la the below. Each hash is a bit taller than it is wide, so
> the pyramid itself is also be taller than it is wide.
>
> ```
>        #
>       ##
>      ###
>     ####
>    #####
>   ######
>  #######
> ########
> ```
>
> The program we’ll write will be called mario. And let’s allow the user
> to decide just how tall the pyramid should be by first prompting them
> for a positive integer between, say, 1 and 8, inclusive.

However I have tried many ways, two of which are these:

1. [code mariov1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAYmc.jpg)
2. After looking at some Stack Overflow attempts, it now looks like this:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

string hash(int);

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (n < 0 || n > 8);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n-1-i; j++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
            {
                printf(".");
            }
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    

}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Do you really need to use that do-while loop? I think the question wanted to prompt the user for height only once

Comment: You have 3 nested loops, which isn't right. The outer loop is for each line. Then inside that you want one loop that prints leading spaces, and then another loop that prints `'#'` characters. That is three loops but not organised the same way – there is only one level of nesting.

Comment: @AbhayAravinda I think the idea of the `while` loop is to input a number within the required range, with another attempt if not.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ohh, you are right! Thank you so much! It was so close, but I couldn't see it.

Comment: @AbhayAravinda Yes, as WeatherVane said, that was for the prompt to repeat until an input within range (1-8) is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int n;
do
{
    n = get_int("Height: ");
}
while (n < 1 || n > 8);
// this for loop makes new lines
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    // here I have two for loops nested inside the above for loop,
    // I previously made the mistake of having two inner loops nested.
    
    // this 2nd for loop prints n-1-i spaces
    // because if n=5, then in the 4th row, there will be 5-1-3 spaces/dots
    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    // this 3rd for loop prints i+1 hashes
    // because if n=5, then in the 4th row, there will be 3+1 hashes. 
    // (3 because you count from 0)
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suriyu, to add to what Weather Vane said. To pass it through Check50, you'll still need to make small tweaks to the code so that it passes through all CS50 tests.

For the do-while loop, `n <=0` instead of `n < 0` to ask for an input when n = 0, because the specification demands a minimum of one brick (1 to 8 both inclusive).

You need only the two loops, don't print extra characters not specified in the problem set, ex: `printf(".");`

All the best with CS50, it's going to be a fun experience!

Comment: Thanks @Anil George, yes, I already took care of it and solved the problem, thanks! Well, I actually used ´´´n < 1´´´ instead of n <= 0, but that worked as well :D

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height of the pyramid is:\n");


    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 8); //condition to get a number from 1-8 from the user
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //loop for height
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++) //loop for spaces on left pyramid
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < i + 1; k++) // loop for hashes on left pyramid
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf(" "); // spacing between pyramids
        for (int p = 0; p <= i; p++) //loop for right pyramid
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

This is the advanced version of the problem if you decide to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach. Instead of iteratively printing blanks, followed by iteratively printing number signs, this version creates a buffer (size defined by a precompiler constant - currently set to 8, change it if you want to allow bigger pyramids), then for each row in the pyramid it first fills the buffer with number signs, then overlays the beginning of the line with the proper number of spaces, and then prints it:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSIZE 8

int main(void)
  {
  int size, spaces;
  char buf[MAXSIZE+1];
  
  do
    size = get_int("Height: ");
  while (size < 0 || size > MAXSIZE);

  buf[size] = '\0';

  for(spaces = size-1 ; spaces >= 0 ; --spaces)
    printf("%s\n", (char *)memset(memset(buf, '#', size), ' ', spaces));
  }
```

### EDIT

And here's yet another approach which builds the entire output block in an array in memory and then prints it using a single call to `puts`:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSIZE 8
#define TOTSIZE ((MAXSIZE+1) * MAXSIZE)

int main(void)
  {
  int size, spaces;
  char buf[TOTSIZE+1];
  
  do
    size = get_int("Height: ");
  while (size < 0 || size > MAXSIZE);

  memset(buf, '\n', (size+1)*size);
  buf[((size+1)*size)] = '\0';

  for(char *p = buf, spaces = size-1 ; *p != '\0' ; p += size+1, --spaces)
    memset(memset(p, '#', size), ' ', spaces);

  puts(buf);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an option that likely works best:

from cs50 import get_int

while True:

```
n=get_int("Enter Height: ")

if n>=1 and n<=8:

    break
```

for i in range(0, n-1):

```
print(" " * (n - (i+1)) + "#" * (i+1))
```